# Passing Click events from GeoJsonLayers to all lower index layers

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson, layer

Im Implementing layers on google maps in Android using `GeoJson Utility Library`. Layers only contains Polygons as Features. I can set feature listener as below

```
layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {

                    Log.i("GeoJsonClick", "Feature clicked: " + feature.getProperty("AName"));

                }
            });
```

When user click on map,This listener consume click event but I also want to trigger OnMapClickListener to get Lat/Lng of clicked position but I know click event will not passed to lower index objects on map as mentioned in Docs

> Note: If multiple overlays or shapes (markers, polylines, polygons,
>   circles and/or ground overlays) are overlaid on top of each other, the
>   click event is cycled through the cluster of markers first, then
>   triggered for other clickable overlays or shapes based on their
>   z-index values. At most one event is triggered per click. In other
>   words, the click is not passed down to the overlays or shapes with
>   lower z-index values. Read more about marker z-index and click
>   events..

But I want to consume click event on both places i.e at layer (Polygon level) and Map Level. how I could achieve this?